# Are there any resources on SO that can be used as a beginner guide?

Tags: discussion

When I have interest in a new topic, usually I start to read one or a few books and articles about it. But, as a newcomer to the topic, it is hard to decide whether what I am reading is good or out-dated and misleading. Here on Stack Overflow we have tons of people who went through the study on that topic, so they already know the knowledge newcomers come for.

So my question is: Is there a place here on SO where we can utilize these people's knowledge to help a newcomer getting started about the topic of their choice?

Because I can't ask for any general help, only specific questions?

Comment: Did you notice the tag wiki's?

Comment: Nope. Could you explain?

Comment: Just search for [beginners guide](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginners+guide+is%3Aq) on Stack Overflow search. You will get a list of *historically locked* questions which are all very useful. But as already mentioned tag wiki's are the best

Comment: I slightly edited your question by removing the noise when the question was closed and reworded your question slightly Please check if that still fits.

Comment: @gnat ahhhh so that's how you access tag wikis

Comment: Related: [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start)

Answer (score 17):

First of all, Stack Overflow is not a site were you'll find tutorial, courses or training material. That kind of content doesn't fit well in the Q and A model.

And you already noticed that unleashing the shared knowledge of all those experienced users here by asking to recommend some books, videos, etc. is not welcome and rather harshly close voted and downvoted.

There is however a carefully kept secret source of knowledge. It is so special it only gets revealed when asked for and after that the messenger is ki.....

You may have noticed that questions have tags, like [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). All tags have an excerpt and a wiki.

The excerpt is the small text that you see when you hover over the tag. It explains in a few words when the tag should be used.

If you click on the tag however you'll find just under the excerpt the [learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) link. If you click that the secret world is revealed to you. More often than not high-rep users spend time to add references to off-site resources, official documentation, often asked duplicates, etc. It is **the place** to find off-site recommendations.

[image: Tag wiki with learn more link]

Maybe you're not so lucky about the topic you choose and its accompanying tag and you find the tag wiki is empty. In that case you can start creating one and fill it with the resource you find while doing your research on Google, vendor sites, etc. You can even ask a question on Meta to see if the community wants to help you create/edit/update that wiki.

You'll find a few blog post about tags and their wiki's [here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) and [here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/).

And finally there are some posts from the early ages of Stack Overflow. [Searching for them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginners+guide+is%3Aq) will find interesting historical locked posts, as pointed out by [Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao).